# Inserting Values into MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP array that has several values in it, corresponding to different banner ads. Let's say $a is called, which would be the 0th value in the array. I have a field in the table *impressions*, likewise called *0*, that holds an integer. I want to call this integer from this field, increment it, and put it back in the same row.

To oversimplify. I want to call up the number of impressions the current ad shown has. Say ad $a has 500 impressions. I want to increment that number, to 501, and put it back in the table.

I hope I explained well enough. Here's my code so far:

```
$ads = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j);
$rand = rand(0,9);
print($ads[$rand]);
$writeVar = $rand;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","delives0_ads","ads");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delives0_ads", $con);
$sqlCmd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions ('$writeVar');");
$sqlCmd++;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO impressions ('$writeVar`) VALUES ('$sqlCmd');");
mysql_close($con);
```

Edit: Here is the structure in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `impressions` (
  `0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `9` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: @Andrei Korchagin - Fuzzy question, redundant sql, and problematic sql syntax. Mind to update your question with the table schema ?

Comment: If `$writeVar` is the actual ID of th ad why would you increment it? IF you do this the impression will no longer be associated with the ad that generated it.

Comment: What format would you like the schema to be in? I tried making it as text but it was a formatting nightmare.

Comment: Also, $writeVar would change every impression, so it's just a very temporary holder of the ID of the ad.

Comment: @Andrei Korchagin - use the \G, like `show create table YOUR_TABLE\G`

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Nevermind. Edited with schema.

Comment: You might want to start over. That schema shows a complete unfamiliarity with relational databases.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a SELECT and UPDATE query to increment a column in a table.

Just send one UPDATE query [example]:

```
UPDATE impressions SET views = views + 1 WHERE ad_id = 3
```

Throw out all the code you've written as none of what you posted is correct. Definitely do not use the database table you designed.

If I might suggest a book or two:

[http://www.amazon.com/Build-Database-Driven-Using-MySQL/dp/0980576814/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980576814)

[http://www.amazon.com/Simply-SQL-Rudy-Limeback/dp/0980455251](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980455251)

Comment: I think the problem is with how I've structured my tables now. I just have the tables made as per my schema, but it seems one-dimensional. I have nowhere to put anything like "views", "ad_id", or anything of the sort.

Comment: Then create a new schema. Here's something more appropriate: 

CREATE TABLE impressions (ad_id INT PRIMARY KEY, views INT DEFAULT 0); -- You will have one row per ad, and that ad's row will contain how many times the ad has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well... `$sqlCmd` holds no data, you have to `mysql_fetch_array();` (this will fetch the data from query) before starting to manipulate with data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Plus, your `mysql_query();` syntax is wrong. See manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

## EDIT:

```
mysql_select_db("delives0_ads", $con);
$sqlCmd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions WHERE `something` = '$writeVar';"); // replace something with your needed identifier in database structure
$sqlCmd = mysql_fetch_array($sqlCmd); // will fetch data in array
$yourData = $sqlCmd['what_you_want_to_get_from_table']; // what_you_want..._table is the variable you want to increment.
$yourData++;
mysql_query("UPDATE impressions SET `yourvariable` = '$yourData' WHERE `something` = '$writeVar';"); // updates data
mysql_close($con);
```

If you could provide database structure, we could help you get the perfect script!

P.S. Have no idea if this actually works (cannot test, haven't used plain mysql syntax for a long time), but I think it should. <s>In case it doesn't, the problem is at `$yourData = $sqlCmd[0]...`, you just have to remove the `[0]`.</s>

Comment: mysql_fetch_array stores a single row into an array, it does not populate a multidimensional array containing all the rows and their columns. Omit the [0].

Comment: Thanks, thought so already, but wasn't sure, I've made my own database class and have forgot a bit about plain mysql syntaxes.

Comment: what can be wrong with such a primitive *PHP function* like mysql_query?

Answer (score -1):

A thing kind of off-topic, but still related to you learning php/MySQL:

From what I know when you do queries it's better to add vars like this: **'".$var."'** instead of **'$var'**

To understand better what I'm saying I'll show you on your code above. So instead of:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions ('$writeVar');");
```

you will have this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions ('".$writeVar."');");
```

I don't remember where I read this, but it was something related to optimizing a query speed.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with query speed, with queries in general and with common sense at all. It's just matter style and anyone is free to choose their favorite one. As for me the first one is way more smooth.

Comment: As I said - I know I've read this some time ago. I didn't said it's a rule, I just said that I remember seeing this on an article...

Comment: So, this article was wrong. And now can you advise someone in learning php/MySQL, if you understand not a bit of it?